# How to name array elements in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I fetch a record from database.

In that I have an array.

```
$new_val = explode(',',$param->arg_2);
```

When I var_dump it I get this:

```
0 => string 'Profile1' (length=8)
1 => string 'Profile2' (length=8)
2 => string 'Profile3' (length=8)
```

How Can I Get this in var_dump :

```
Profile1 => string 'Profile1' (length=8)
Profile2 => string 'Profile2' (length=8)
Profile3 => string 'Profile3' (length=8)
```

Comment: That means you have to make array from comma separated string?

Comment: Yes @SanjayChaudhari

Comment: But what happens if some of indexes have same values? They will be override. So this is not always good practice.

Comment: @aslawin You are right but as per my requirement i have to get this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the code:

```
$new_val = explode(',',$param->arg_2);
```

Add:

```
$new_val = array_combine($new_val, array_values($new_val));
```

Comment: This is great Thanks Man

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$new_array=array();
    foreach($new_val as $nv)
    {
    $new_array[$nv]=$nv;
    }
    var_dump($new_array);
```

Comment: No, it gives me this 0 => string ''Profile1'=>'Profile A'' (length=23)
  1 => string ''Profile2'=>'Profile B'' (length=23)
  2 => string ''Profile3'=>'Profile C'' (length=23)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = array('Profile 1', 'Profile 2', 'Profile 3'); //its your exploded string

$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
    $newArray[$value] = $value;

var_dump($newArray);
```

And result is:

```
array(3) {
  ["Profile 1"]=>
  string(9) "Profile 1"
  ["Profile 2"]=>
  string(9) "Profile 2"
  ["Profile 3"]=>
  string(9) "Profile 3"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_combine` — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

Try this

```
$array = explode(',',$param->arg_2);
$names = array_combine($array, $array);
var_dump($names);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(0 => 'Profile1',
1 => 'Profile2',
2 => 'Profile3');

$vals = array_values($arr);

var_dump(array_combine($vals, $arr));
```

should output

```
array(3) { ["Profile1"]=> string(8) "Profile1" ["Profile2"]=> string(8) "Profile2" ["Profile3"]=> string(8) "Profile3" }
```

Answer (score 0):

While searching thorught PHP guide I came across this and eve this helped me:

```
eval("\$new_val = array (".$param->arg_2.");");
```